# subclassing a class which contains a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to change around a class to more match my specifications. I start by subclassing the main class

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
class SpecialSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
  def __repr__(self):
    # I change this around a bit
```

the `dir` of SQLAlchemy shows that it contains a `Model` class, which I would like to modify in a specific way. However, `Model` is bound to the class of SQLAlchemy. What is the appropriate way to

```
>>> from app import db
>>> type(db)
<class 'app/utilities/SpecialSQLAlchemy'>
>>> dir(db)[dir(db).index('Model')]
'Model'
```

I want to change the `__repr__` on the Model contained within the SQLAlchemy class. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a straightforward way:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
class SpecialSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
  def __repr__(self):
     # I change this around a bit
  class Model(SQLAlchemy.Model):
     def __repr__(self):
         # changes here
```

Comment: this seems not to have worked, but probably because of a mistake of my own. I did the following to check if it is a class like this: `[x for x in l if inspect.isclass(getattr(db, x))]` and 'Model' did still show up.

Comment: It won't work if the Model class is used in a special manner, for example, bound during class creation in a metaclass. You could also try to monkeypatch the original Model "repr" method - just assign a new function to it in a line like `SQLAlchemy.Model.__repr__ = my_repr_implementation`